# String to Csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, formatting

I have the following string

```
string = "OGC Number | LT No | Job /n 9625878 | EPP3234 | 1206545/n" and continues on
```

I am trying to write it to a .CSV file where it will look like this:

```
OGC Number | LT No | Job   
------------------------------
9625878   | EPP3234  | 1206545
9708562   | PGP43221 | 1105482
9887954   | BCP5466  | 1025454
```

- where each newline in the string is a new row
- where each "|" in the sting is a new column

I am having trouble getting the formatting.

I think I need to use:

```
string.split('/n')
string.split('|')
```

Thanks.

Windows 7, Python 2.6

Comment: What does your program look like?  What trouble are you having?

Comment: Updated in response to comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in using a third party module. [Prettytable](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable/) is very useful and has a nice set of features to deal with and print tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
text="""
OGC Number | LT No | Job   
------------------------------
9625878   | EPP3234  | 1206545
9708562   | PGP43221 | 1105482
9887954   | BCP5466  | 1025454"""

import csv
lines = text.splitlines()
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    csvout.writerow(lines[0]) # header
    for row in lines[2:]: # content
        csvout.writerow([col.strip() for col in row.split('|')])
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Oops, I missunderstood your question!

The code below will use two regular expressions to do the modifications.

```
import re

str="""OGC Number | LT No | Job   
------------------------------
9625878   | EPP3234  | 1206545
9708562   | PGP43221 | 1105482
9887954   | BCP5466  | 1025454
"""
# just setup above 

# remove all lines with at least 4 dashes
str=re.sub( r'----+\n', '', str )

# replace all pipe symbols with their 
# surrounding spaces by single semicolons
str=re.sub( r' +\| +', ';', str )

print str
```